# Powershell Remoting Access Denied

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have enabled PSRemoting on the server:

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
```

I also checked that the port is listening properly on the correct IPs by using the command:

```
winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener
```

Yet when I try to create a New-PSSession to loopback address:

```
New-PSSession ::1
```

It gives the following error:

```
New-PSSession : [[::1]] Connecting to remote server [::1] failed with the following error message : Access is denied.
For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-PSSession ::1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: 
(System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

Any help in troubleshooting this would be appreciated!

Here is the output for

```
winrm get winrm/config
```

Not sure if it helps:

```
Config
    MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 500
    MaxTimeoutms = 60000
    MaxBatchItems = 32000
    MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
    Client
        NetworkDelayms = 5000
        URLPrefix = wsman
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Digest = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = true
            CredSSP = false
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        TrustedHosts
    Service
        RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
        MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
        MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
        EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
        MaxConnections = 300
        MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = false
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = false
            CredSSP = false
            CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        IPv4Filter = *
        IPv6Filter = *
        EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
        EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
        CertificateThumbprint
        AllowRemoteAccess = true
    Winrs
        AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
        IdleTimeout = 7200000
        MaxConcurrentUsers = 10
        MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
        MaxProcessesPerShell = 25
        MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 1024
        MaxShellsPerUser = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the PowerShell as administrator. Having elevated privileges resolved the issue in my case.

Comment: That doesn't work. I get the same error. The remoting command should work without running as administrator as I have tested in another server.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened with me. I was running the Powershell ISE in admin mode, both computers had the correct privileges. After some investigation, I found out that the time was wrong on the remote system. Fixed that and I was able to then remote in.